# Exception while parsing date string using DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java

I am trying to convert EST date string to zonedDateTime object via below code -

```
@Test
public void dateTest() {
    String date = "Fri Feb 26 00:00:00 EST 2016";//"Fri Feb 26 00:00:00 EST 2016"
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz YYYY");
    ZonedDateTime zoneDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(date,dateTimeFormatter);
    System.out.println(zoneDateTime.toString());
}
```

but getting below exception -

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Fri Feb 26 00:00:00 EST 2016' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfMonth=26, MicroOfSecond=0, MinuteOfHour=0, MilliOfSecond=0, MonthOfYear=2, HourOfAmPm=0, DayOfWeek=5, WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2016, NanoOfSecond=0, SecondOfMinute=0},ISO,America/New_York of type java.time.format.Parsed
>       at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(Unknown Source)
>       at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.citi.uno.alerts.controller.XMLTest.dateTest(XMLTest.java:23)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:670)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfMonth=26, MicroOfSecond=0, MinuteOfHour=0, MilliOfSecond=0, MonthOfYear=2, HourOfAmPm=0, DayOfWeek=5, WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2016, NanoOfSecond=0, SecondOfMinute=0},ISO,America/New_York of type java.time.format.Parsed
>       at java.time.ZonedDateTime.from(Unknown Source)
>       at java.time.format.Parsed.query(Unknown Source)
>       ... 26 more
>   Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfMonth=26, MicroOfSecond=0, MinuteOfHour=0, MilliOfSecond=0, MonthOfYear=2, HourOfAmPm=0, DayOfWeek=5, WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2016, NanoOfSecond=0, SecondOfMinute=0},ISO,America/New_York of type java.time.format.Parsed
>       at java.time.LocalDate.from(Unknown Source)
>       ... 28 more

Please help!!

Comment: @Tunaki: thanks for sharing the actual thread. I have gone through the thread, but not able to catch, what is wrong with my code. Please help!!

Comment: In your pattern `EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz YYYY`, there are multiple issues: first, `"hh"` is AM/PM hour, not 24-hour. And `YYYY` is the week-year not the year (`yyyy`). Depending on your system locale, you will also need to specify `Locale.ENGLISH` since you're parsing Month written in English.

Comment: Thanks...i changed the YYYY to yyyy and HH to hh, but then too got the same exception.

Comment: Check your locale, it needs to be English: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(..., Locale.ENGLISH)`.

Comment: tried that too, but no luck :(

Comment: This code works for me-------------------------------------------------------------------String valueDate = trade.get("valueDate").toString();
   DateTimeFormatter parsingDateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd H:mm:ss z yyyy");
   DateTimeFormatter desiredDateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
   ZonedDateTime zoneDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(valueDate,parsingDateTimeFormatter);
   return desiredDateTimeFormatter.format(zoneDateTime);